# Cant find symbol - Error trying to call method

Tags: java, class

**First of all here is my method:**

```
    public static Complex plus(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumer b) {
    double real = a.r + b.r;
    double imaginar = a.i + b.i;
    ComplexNumber sum = new ComplexNumber (real, imaginar);
    return sum;
}
```

And when I try to call it in main class i cant. Error: "Cant find symbol"
System.out.println(plus); // doesnt work.

If someone want whole code i can put it but variables **are not on English**, so.. Sorry

Here is my Complex class: (variables not on English):

```
public class KompleksniBroj {

private double r;
private double i;

public KompleksniBroj() {
}

public KompleksniBroj(double realan, double imaginarni) {
    this.r = realan;
    this.i = imaginarni;
}

public double getR() {
    return r;
}

public void setR(double r) {
    this.r = r;
}

public double getI() {
    return i;
}

public void setI(double i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public static KompleksniBroj plus(KompleksniBroj a, KompleksniBroj b) {
    double realan = a.r + b.r;
    double imaginarni = a.i + b.i;
    KompleksniBroj sum = new KompleksniBroj(realan, imaginarni);
    return sum;
}

public KompleksniBroj konjugovan() {
    return new KompleksniBroj(r, -i);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "KompleksniBroj{" + "r = " + r + ", i = " + i + '}';
}

}
```

Main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    KompleksniBroj a = new KompleksniBroj(5.0, 6.0);
    KompleksniBroj b = new KompleksniBroj(-3.0, 4.0);

    System.out.println(plus(a, b));

    }
```

Comment: Don't post the whole code. Post a complete but minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Also, could you please post the full error message?

Comment: Where is `plus` declared?  Is it in scope?

Comment: "Cannot find symbol. Symbol: Variable plus."

Comment: @JoeC plus is my method name. And when i try to call it, doesnt work

Comment: And you stil haven't posted a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. You haven't even posted the code that causes the error in the first place. The code matters when you have an error in the code.

Comment: How to post code in comment?

Comment: What are you expecting `System.out.println(plus)` to do?  Since `plus` is a method, you probably want to call it and pass a couple of arguments, like `System.out.println(plus(oneComplexNumber, anotherComplexNumber));`

Comment: Don't post code in a comment.  Update your original question with _all_ your code, since the error is not in the code that you've shown.

Comment: I posted code in post

Comment: No, you need to post the code where the error is.  It's not the `KompleksniBroj` class that has the problem - it's the `main` method where you're using it.

Comment: Presumably that `plus(a, b)` should be `KompleksniBroj.plus(a, b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `plus()` is a static method of the class `KompleksniBroj`. 
Use it qualified by the class name:

```
KompleksniBroj.plus()
```

but you also need to provide 2 arguments which must be properly initialized `KompleksniBroj` objects, like:

```
KompleksniBroj k1 = new KompleksniBroj(1, 1);
KompleksniBroj k2 = new KompleksniBroj(2, 2);
```

If you have defined correctly the `toString()` method in `KompleksniBroj` class, then you can call:

```
System.out.println(KompleksniBroj.plus(k1, k2));
```

Comment: Are you still here? Can i ask you something?

Comment: The best way to ask somebody something is in a new question.

Comment: Now i have new problem. I cant call new method, no static

Comment: What new method?

Comment: Where i can put code?

In my post, public class konjugovan, i cant call it

Comment: If it is related to your question, edit the question. If not post another question with all the relevant code.

Comment: Its related to my question litteraly. I just cant call my another method, same error.
Method is konjugovan, method after plus method

Comment: You can't call it like plus() because it is not **static**. If you have an object `k` of the class `KompleksniBroj` you can call it like `k.konjugovan()`

Comment: Don't make the same mistake again. Ask another question and post all the relevant code in the question. But before that, read your text book about classes, objects and methods.

Comment: It's not related to your question.  If you can't find anything in your textbook, or in other Stack Overflow questions, that tells you how to call a non-static method - for example by putting a dot after an expression, like `System.out.println(k1.konjugovan());` - then post a completely new question.  But make sure you include all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

`plus()` is a static method of the class `KompleksniBroj`. Not a static methd of the `Main` class. So to call it from `Main`, you need to use

```
KompleksniBroj.plus(...)
```

i.e.

```
System.out.println(KompleksniBroj.plus(a, b));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that work! And I want to apologize to everyone for the bad explained!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the class name that has the static method to call the method.

If `class A`, has a method named `static void foo()`, outside of `class A`, you need to call it like this: `A.foo()`

so in your case: `KompleksniBroj.plus(a, b)`

Comment: I made a mistake while rewriting the code in English, that line is good. And how to post code in comment?

Comment: Then could it be that you have defined the method outside the scope of the class you are trying to call it in?

Comment: As far as I know you can not, edit your original post.